# youtube-dl sees all playlists as empty

Tags: bash, youtube-dl

As the title says. It's been working fine, but this behavior started yesterday. I've upgraded and reinstalled with homebrew and even tried running the executable downloaded directly from youtube-dl.org. The following code reproduces the behavior I'm seeing:

```
 ---------------- | *****@********:~ 
$ youtube-dl --flat-playlist --verbose https://www.youtube.com/user/onearmsteve4192/videos
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['--flat-playlist', '--verbose', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/onearmsteve4192/videos']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out utf-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2020.11.01.1
[debug] Python version 3.9.0 (CPython) - macOS-10.15.6-x86_64-i386-64bit
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 3.3.3, ffprobe 3.3.3
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube:user] onearmsteve4192: Downloading channel page
[youtube:playlist] UU3x3gDTqUYy_bFZWS-U_mZQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: UU3x3gDTqUYy_bFZWS-U_mZQ
[youtube:playlist] playlist UU3x3gDTqUYy_bFZWS-U_mZQ: Downloading 0 videos
[download] Finished downloading playlist: UU3x3gDTqUYy_bFZWS-U_mZQ
```

The flag `--flat-playlist` just tells it to print the videos instead of downloading them, but it doesn't work without that either (I'm using `-x --archive` in production but it does the same thing)

Comment: Are you aware of the RIAA take down notice for youtube_dl recently?

Comment: @Rob What does that have to do with anything? They only took down Github, not the PyPI package.

Comment: I think the issue may just be that a user page, or their page of uploads is not a playlist.

Comment: No, it's user page + ```/videos``` which is the playlist page for a user's uploads. In any case the same behavior occurs with a playlist as well.

Comment: yes, channel and playlist download seems to be broken at the moment on youtube-dl. see [yourube-dl sees all channel links as empty](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/jr56fs/yourubedl_sees_all_channel_links_as_empty/)

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Thank you!

Comment: It is back but it is still not working.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar check the subreddit linked by Marco for a working version.